# Display jquery ui autocomplete with categories horizontally and not vertically

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to display the autocomplete results horizontally instead of the default(vertical). I was able to do it but the issue is I cant select the item from the drop down anymore. I think because I used div instead of ul. And if I use ul jquery appends some un-wanted classes inline. Which messes up the horizontal behaviour

HTML

```
  <label for="search">Search: </label>
<input id="search">
```

CSS

```
#search {
    width: 500px;
  }
 .ui-autocomplete {
    display: flex;
    width: auto !important;
}

.ui-autocomplete-category {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: .2em .4em;
    margin: .8em 0 .2em;
    line-height: 1.5;
  }
  .ui-autocomplete-category ul{
    padding:0;
  }
  .submenu {
    font-weight: normal;
  }
```

JS

```
$.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _create: function() {
      this._super();
      this.widget().menu( "option", "items", "> :not(.ui-autocomplete-category)" );
    },
    _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
      var that = this,
        currentCategory = "";
      $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
        var li, submenuUl;
        if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
             var elt = $("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>");
             var submenu = $("<div class='submenu "+ item.category +"'></div>");
             elt.append(submenu);
             ul.append(elt);
             currentCategory = item.category;
          }
          submenuUl = ul.find("."+item.category+"");
          li = that._renderItemData(submenuUl, item );
          if ( item.category ) {
            li.attr( "aria-label", item.category + " : " + item.label );
          }
      });
    }
  });
```

https://codepen.io/nitinmendiratta/pen/aMMeOz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is widget tweeking I like!

The main mistake was not having a `ul` as direct parent of your custom `li`.
Then, Those custom `li` need the `ui-menu-item` class in order to be selected...

Lastly, you have to *"override"* the styling of the nested `ul` using `!important`. So they will be displayed as `block` with a `relative` position. Incidentally, without border...

And I removed an icon strangely showing...

It works fine in [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/YgMzgW?editors=0110). It needed an additional CSS rule to work in the below snippet. *(Don't ask me why!)*

```js
$.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
  _create: function() {
    this._super();
    this.widget().menu( "option", "items", "> :not(.ui-autocomplete-category)" );
  },
  _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
    var that = this,
        currentCategory = "";
    $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
      var li, submenuUl;
      if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
        var elt = $("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>");
        var submenu = $("<div class='submenu "+ item.category +"'><ul></ul></div>");  // Added <ul></ul>
        elt.append(submenu);
        ul.append(elt);
        currentCategory = item.category;
      }
      submenuUl = ul.find("."+item.category+" ul"); // added +" ul"
      li = that._renderItemData(submenuUl, item );
      if ( item.category ) {
        li.attr( "aria-label", item.category + " : " + item.label ).addClass("ui-menu-item"); // Added the addClass()
      }
    });
  }
});


// Actual Code
$(function() {
  var data = [
    { label: "annhhx10", category: "Products" },
    { label: "annk K12", category: "Products" },
    { label: "annttop C13", category: "Products" },
    { label: "anders andersson", category: "People" },
    { label: "andreas andersson", category: "People" },
    { label: "andreas johnson", category: "People" }
  ];

  $( "#search" ).catcomplete({
    delay: 0,
    source: data,
    select: function(item, ui){ // Added item, ui --- Arguments were missing.
      console.log(ui.item.value);
      $( "#search" ).val( ui.item.value );
      return false;
    }
  }); 
});
```

```css
#search {
  width: 500px;
}
.ui-autocomplete {
  display: flex;
  width: auto !important;
}

.ui-autocomplete-category {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: .2em .4em;
  margin: .8em 0 .2em;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.ui-autocomplete-category ul{
  padding:0;
}
.submenu {
  font-weight: normal;
}

/* ADDED STYLE */
.ui-autocomplete>li>div>ul{
  display: block !important;
  position: relative !important;
  border: 0 !important;
}
span.ui-menu-icon{
  display:none !important;
}

/* ADDED for the SO snippet only !! Not needed on CodePen */
.ui-autocomplete>li{
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<label for="search">Search: </label>
<input id="search">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working as expected. Appreciate it :)